# Empty statistics when declaring a column as primary key and adding data to the table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

If I declare a column in a table as a primary key, stats are created for that column but they are empty even after I add substantial data to the table. Had I added the primary key to the able after adding the data, stats would be populated with meaningful info. Why does creating a primary key beforehand does not result in meaningful stats, no matter how much data I add to the table?

**Case 1**: here is the code to create a table using primary key:

```
create table t
(
    col1  int primary key,
    col2 int 
)
go

--insert 150000 records into table
insert into t (col1, col2)
    select top 150000 
        row_number() over (order by (select null)), 
        row_number() over (order by (select null)) 
    from 
        master.dbo.syscolumns 
    cross join 
        master.dbo.syscolumns as c
```

**Case 2**: here is the code to create a table with the primary key created after data is ingested into the table:

```
create table t
(
    col1 int not null,
    col2 int 
)
go

--insert 150000 records into table
insert into t (col1, col2)
    select top 150000 
        row_number() over (order by (select null)), 
        row_number() over (order by (select null)) 
    from 
        master.dbo.syscolumns 
    cross join 
        master.dbo.syscolumns as c

alter table t 
add constraint pk_col1 primary key (col1)
```

For case 1, even if I try to seek into the index by filtering on col1, even then the stats are not updated:

```
select * 
from t 
where col1 = 4050
```

Filtering on a column would normally create stats even if the table is a heap:

```
create table t1
(
    col1  int,
    col2 int 
)
go

--insert 15000 records into table
insert into t (col1, col2)
    select top 150000 
        row_number() over (order by (select null)), 
        row_number() over (order by (select null)) 
    from 
        master.dbo.syscolumns 
    cross join 
        master.dbo.syscolumns as c

select * 
from t1 
where col1 = 4050
```

Comment: Did you try updating statistics after inserting into the table with the PK?

Comment: I shouldn't have to update stats manually.

Comment: @umbersar what version of sql server do you have?

Comment: @RuslanTolkachev I have explained the problem more clearly this time with just using primary keys. The sql server is 2017

Comment: Stats will be updated when you run a query against the table and SQL Server determines the stats will be useful for optimization. Try running a query like `SELECT * FROM t where col1 BETWEEN 1 AND 10;`.

Comment: @DanGuzman OK. That query did update the stats. But the one I used earlier, "select * from t where col1=4050", did not. Strange.

Comment: @umbersar, that query is a no-brainer; singleton select of all columns by a clustered primary key. A query that could return multiple rows is one where stats are useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, as per Microsoft [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/statistics/statistics?view=sql-server-2017):

> The Query Optimizer checks for out-of-date statistics before compiling a query and before executing a cached query plan. Before compiling a query, the Query Optimizer uses the columns, tables, and indexed views in the query predicate to determine which statistics might be out-of-date. Before executing a cached query plan, the Database Engine verifies that the query plan references up-to-date statistics. 
>  Starting with SQL Server 2016 (13.x) and under the database compatibility level 130, SQL Server uses a decreasing, dynamic statistics update threshold that adjusts according to the number of rows in the table. This is calculated as the square root of the product of 1000 and the current table cardinality. For example if your table contains 2 million rows, then the calculation is sqrt (1000 * 2000000) = 44721.359.

Basically you need to run a query first on the index before it will create/update stats.
I've tried to run

```
SELECT * 
FROM [dbo].[t]
WHERE col1  > 100000
```

And stats were updated